# How to download (PDF) files with Python/Scrapy using the Files Pipeline?

Tags: python, scrapy

Using Python 3.7.2 on Windows 10 I'm struggling with the task to let Scrapy v1.5.1 download some PDF files. I followed the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html?highlight=download#using-the-files-pipeline) but I seem to miss something. Scrapy gets me the desired PDF URLs **but downloads nothing**. Also no errors are thrown (at least).

The relevant code is:

scrapy.cfg:

```
[settings]
default = pranger.settings

[deploy]
project = pranger
```

settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'pranger'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['pranger.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'pranger.spiders'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'pranger.pipelines.PrangerPipeline': 300,
    'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1,
}

FILES_STORE = r'C:\pranger_downloaded'

FILES_URLS_FIELD = 'PDF_urls'
FILES_RESULT_FIELD = 'processed_PDFs'
```

pranger_spider.py:

```
import scrapy

class IndexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "index"
    url_liste = []

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://verbraucherinfo.ua-bw.de/lmk.asp?ref=3',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for menupunkt in response.css('div#aufklappmenue'):
            yield {
                'file_urls': menupunkt.css('div.aussen a.innen::attr(href)').getall()
            }
```

items.py:

```
import scrapy    

class PrangerItem(scrapy.Item):
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()
```

All other files are as they were created by the `scrapy startproject` command.
The output of `scrapy crawl index` is:

```
(pranger) C:\pranger>scrapy crawl index
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: pranger)
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.1.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 11 2019, 14:11:50) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018), cryptography 2.5, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'pranger', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'pranger.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['pranger.spiders']}
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline', 'pranger.pipelines.PrangerPipeline']
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-02-20 15:45:18 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-02-20 15:45:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://verbraucherinfo.ua-bw.de/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-02-20 15:45:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://verbraucherinfo.ua-bw.de/lmk.asp?ref=3> (referer: None)
2019-02-20 15:45:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://verbraucherinfo.ua-bw.de/lmk.asp?ref=3>
{'file_urls': ['https://www.lrabb.de/site/LRA-BB-Desktop/get/params_E-428807985/3287025/Ergebnisse_amtlicher_Kontrollen_nach_LFGB_Landkreis_Boeblingen.pdf', <<...and dozens more URLs...>>], 'processed_PDFs': []}
2019-02-20 15:45:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-02-20 15:45:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 469,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 13268,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 20, 14, 45, 19, 166646),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 20, 14, 45, 18, 864509)}
2019-02-20 15:45:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Oh BTW I published the code, just in case: https://github.com/R0byn/pranger/tree/5bfa0df92f21cecee18cc618e9a8e7ceea192403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `FILES_URLS_FIELD` setting tells the pipeline what field of the item contains the urls you want to download.

By default, this is `file_urls`, but if you change the setting, you also need to change the field name (key) you're storing the urls in.

So you have two options -  either use the default setting, or rename your item's field to `PDF_urls` as well.