# Could this selenium code be recreated using scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm interested in getting a better idea of what scrapy can do. Here is a very simple selenium code that interacts with a website, fills in some boxes, clicks some elements and downloads a file. Could this code be replicated using scrapy?, so that a code is written using scrapy that does the exact same thing.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options=Options()
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
   
driver.get("https://www.ons.gov.uk/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("Education and childcare")
click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-search-submit"]').click()
click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h3/a/span').click()
click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/h3/a/span').click()
click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]/a').click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"selenium code be recreated using scrapy"` is also working fine with `SeleniuRequest` which is `superfast` than general selenium. You need scrapy project.It works as headless mode but always get screenshot for each step.

**script:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC




class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'

    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
            url='https://www.ons.gov.uk',
            callback=self.parse,
            wait_time = 3,
            screenshot = True
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        driver = response.meta['driver']
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')

        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "q"))).send_keys("Education and childcare")
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshot_1.png')
        click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-search-submit"]').click()
        driver.save_screenshot('screenshot_2.png')
        click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="results"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/h3/a/span').click()
        click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div[1]/section/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/h3/a/span').click()
        click_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/p[2]/a').click()
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aZ2a.png)

settings.py file:

You have to add the following options in settings.py file

```
# Middleware

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_selenium.SeleniumMiddleware': 800
}


# Selenium
from shutil import which
SELENIUM_DRIVER_NAME = 'chrome'
SELENIUM_DRIVER_EXECUTABLE_PATH = which('chromedriver')
SELENIUM_DRIVER_ARGUMENTS = ['--headless']
```

[SeleniumRequest](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-requests/)

**Output:**

```
'downloader/response_status_count/200'
```

[screenshot of the project looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFzJI.png)

[How to download pdf using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790699/how-to-download-pdf-files-with-python-scrapy-using-the-files-pipeline)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwNPb.png)

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'm new to Python so I may be a little slower to grasp things. Thankfully, I've understood the first half of the script. I'm not too sure what the settings.py file is. I'd kindly like to ask where it is located and how I can update it?. Ultimately, I'm planning to use the power of Scrapy to try and run two different selenium scripts at the same time. I hope it's possible. I posted a question here regarding it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71976269/how-can-i-make-this-selenium-code-run-in-parallel-using-scrapy?noredirect=1#comment127184203_71976269

Comment: @David Copperfield creating scrapy project  and well-familiar with  the project files is  a bit more important but  seems to  be  complex, don't worry about it, definetly you will understand everything but you have to spend more time on it. You can  read and learn about project setting portion from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/email-id-extractor-project-from-sites-in-scrapy-python/). Please a bit more from online and practice  and you will succeed. Thanks

Comment: Just go to you project  folder and  and you will find settings.py file and  open it by clicking and in bellow or anywhere in your setings.py file copy and paste middleware and selenium  portion on it.

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement. I am using Spyder to run my script which I got after installing anaconda. I looked inside my 'anaconda3' folder. I have five 'settings.py' files.  All in different locations. 
"C:\Users\David\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\settings.py"
"C:\Users\David\anaconda3\pkgs\bokeh-2.3.2-py38haa95532_0\Lib\site-packages\bokeh\settings.py"
"C:\Users\David\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\bokeh\settings.py"
"C:\Users\David\anaconda3\pkgs\isort-5.8.0-pyhd3eb1b0_0\site-packages\isort\settings.py"
"C:\Users\David\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\isort\settings.py"

Comment: I'm not too sure which one to update.

Comment: Just curious, when you run the code did it download the pdf document?.

Comment: @David Copperfield,Thanks. No , scrapy didn't download pdf file because  they use media pipeline to download image and pdf and  it's an another question but  according to your question code is working. I've added a link above.

Comment: Regarding the settings.py and PDF question. I posted the question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71990861/where-do-i-save-the-settings-py-file-to-for-this-scrapy-selenium-code-and-also-h